# class not found error while trying to generate jni headers

Tags: android-ndk

why does every time i try to generate jni files, following error pops up?

[image: This is the snapshot of commands i entered]

I have tried specifying class path but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go to classpath and run the command

Follow this guide :
http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/android_ndk.html

> -classpath: in our case, we need the JNIActivity.class which is kept in "**< project-root >\bin\classes**"; and its superclass
>   Android.app.Activity.class which is kept in android.jar under the
>   Android SDK.

The error is coming because the folder contains *.java files and we are looking for *.class files